# How to download files from IBM Python Notebook to local computer?

Tags: ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, data-science-experience, ibm-data-studio

I am trying to save a plot as a file through the Python Notebook in IBM Watson Platform.

After trying

```
localfilenamefromplot = 'foo1.png'
fig = plt.figure()

fig.savefig(localfilenamefromplot)
```

I can't find where the file is stored. I tried to type:

```
! find ~/ -name foo1.png -print
```

And it returns:

```
/gpfs/fs01/user/sc23-e890c70096bffa-bofgdgoi23423464/notebook/work/foo1.png
```

How can I locate this file, and see it? And let's say I want to save many plot-files like this one in a loop, can I directly (in the loop) save them to local computer (export), (without displaying the plots) as it will consume too much space in the IBM Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Your notebook code is running in an IBM cluster. It cannot save to the disk of your own computer, on which your browser is running. The files you save to the "local" file system are saved in the IBM cluster. There's no download option for that file system.

You should save your files directly into a Cloud Object Storage (COS) instance. Or if that is not possible due to API constraints, save them to the "local" file system in the cluster and then copy them from there to COS. From COS, it is possible to download files to your computer.

All recent projects in Watson Studio (formerly Data Science Experience) already use a COS instance for storing your notebooks. You can use that same instance for the data you generate in notebooks. There's a [`project-lib`](https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html) for conveniently accessing COS from your notebook.

Comment: thats exactly the thing! I found that library, but how to use the save_date function? Could you provide a coding example from executing the plot, to saving the data and downloading it?

Comment: I already linked the documentation of project-lib in my answer. For downloading from COS, please look for the COS documentation. No, I cannot provide a coding example.

Comment: Thank you, I really don't like how IBM is managing this things :/ a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

I would say save it to your root by specifying the directory in your file name such as:

```
localfilenamefromplot = '../foo1.png'
fig = plt.figure()

fig.savefig(localfilenamefromplot)
```

This way you can locate it easily. When you type `!ls '../'` in a cell in your notebook you can see your files. You can even create a new folder with `!mkdir '../newfolder'` and save your figures there. But I am also looking for a way to download them and still haven't found it.